# "TypeError: a float is required" even tough i write float()

Tags: python

Trying to put float() everywhere but i still get the same message.

```
def getAmountOfCarbon(volume):
    carbon = 1.8 + 2 * math.log(volume)
    return carbon

    carbon = []
    for listitem in lists:
        carbonlist = getAmountOfCarbon(volume)
        carbon.append(carbonlist)
```

My lists variable is a function:

```
lists = readCSVfile(str1)

print carbon
TypeError: a float is required
```

Where should i put my float()?

edit: the volume comes from:

```
def getVolume(width, height, length):
    volume = (width) * (height) * (length) 
    return volume
```

edit:
I call volume here:

```
volume = []
for listitem in lists:
    volumelist = getVolume(listitem[2], listitem[3], listitem[4])
    volume.append(volumelist)
```

Edit:
Solved it in a different way:

```
def createAnalyseList(lists):
    analyselist = []
    for item in lists:
        height = getHeightType(item[4])
        carbon = getAmountOfCarbon(getVolume(item[2],item[3],item[4]))
        analyselist.append([item[0], item[1], height, carbon])
    print analyselist
    return analyselist
analyselist = createAnalyseList(lists)
```

Comment: show your `lists` variable, please

Comment: When and how does `listitem` magically become `volume`?

Comment: This question is missing some things. First, your indentation is wrong. Then we don't know what getAmountOfCarbon(). You're using the name carbon twice for different things - this is somewhat confusing. In the end we have no idea what throws the error.

Comment: I don't see where you have passed the value for Volume in the code you shared. If you have not, this might be causing the error.

Comment: Is `lists` a list of lists` If so, try `carbonlist = [getAmountOfCarbon(volume) for volume in listitem]`

Comment: Yes, lists is a list of list @tobias_k

Comment: That's the error you would get if you passed (for example) a `str` object to `math.log`. How is `lists` being populated, and where do you actually call `getVolume`?

Comment: You `improved formatting` but do you really know what you are doing? Is it really *your* code?

Comment: It is my code, but i am big newbie trying to do a school assignment @wolf

Comment: I see. I think you erroneously indented the lines after `return carbon` in the first code snippet.

Comment: What does your `readCSVfile` function look like? It appears that you are not converting the data you read from strings into floats.

Comment: StackOverflow is a good place to learn from others. Don't give up!

Comment: BTW, your indentation in several of your code blocks is still incorrect. Indentation is **very** important in Python: the wrong indentation will cause your code to crash, or even worse, it will still run, but it will do something different to what you think it's doing.

Comment: In there _any_ difference in the two big blocks in your `readCSVfile` function _except_ the file name?

Comment: I read that it is against the rules to thank people, but thanks for trying to help me with my messy code :)
I have edited in my readCSVfile function, and the try: part is supposed to convert the numbers to ints and floats

Comment: @tobias_k no there is no difference except the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think now I see what's the problem. It seems you are doing this in your code:

```
lists = readCSVfile(str1)

volume = []
for listitem in lists:
    volumelist = getVolume(listitem[2], listitem[3], listitem[4])
    volume.append(volumelist)

carbon = []
for listitem in lists:
    carbonlist = getAmountOfCarbon(volume)
    carbon.append(carbonlist)
```

Here, `volume` in the second loop is still the entire list of volumes created in the first loop, and you are trying to convert that *list* to one "carbon" value (thus the `TypeError`) and append it to the `carbon` list for each value in the original `lists`! That does not seem to make much sense.

Instead, try this:

```
carbon = []
for listitem in volume:
    carbonlist = getAmountOfCarbon(listitem)
    carbon.append(carbonlist)
```

Or using `map` (Python 2 only):

```
carbon = map(getAmountOfCarbon, volume)
```

Or as a list comprehension:

```
carbon = [getAmountOfCarbon(x) for x in volume]
```

Or all at once (not tested):

```
carbon = [getAmountOfCarbon(volume(*lst[2:5])) for lst in lists]
```

Also, note that the code in your `readCSVfile` function is all duplicate. You can just do like this:

```
def readCSVfile(str1):
    with open(str1 + '.csv', 'r+') as f:
        ....
```

Comment: it worked fine until i added another for loop for another calculation, now i get the same message again.
The problem must be elswhere

Comment: @ErikAngerfistNyström To be honest, I'd rather think that you made the same mistake again.

Comment: I got some help from an student at my university who guided me to a completely different approach on this problem.
I will put it as an edit in my post.
Thank you for the help, it was really nice :)
@tobias_k

Answer (score 0):

Making a few changes, assuming your lists variable is a list of ints/floats I've executed your example successfully (also assumed that `listitem` and `volume`are the same):

```
import math

def getAmountOfCarbon(volume):
    carbon = 1.8 + 2 * math.log(volume)
    return carbon

carbon = []

lists = [1.0, 5, 47, 89]

for listitem in lists:
    carbonlist = getAmountOfCarbon(listitem)
    carbon.append(carbonlist)

print carbon
```

Comment: Good guess. Let's hope that the asker cares for making the question match the answer. ;-)

Comment: This gives the same Error

Comment: I've tried to run this version in python 2.7 and the modified version for python 3.4 and both output `[1.8, 5.018875824868201, 9.500295203420118, 10.77727273946428]`.

Comment: The OP is reading number strings from a CSV but it looks like he's not converting those strings to `float`s or `int`s.

Comment: Haven't noticed he edited the question, guess you're right @PM2Ring, if that's the issue Erik can cast each value to float ([more here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int))